# How to say "He wants it less spicy" in Japanese

Tags: word-choice, english-to-japanese, comparative-constructions

Whats the best way to tell someone, that a person wants something less spicy? あまり辛くほしくない would be a way to say it differently, but I'm looking for "less...".

Comment: "あまり辛くほしくない" -- is incorrect. (「～く」(形容詞連用形)+「ほしい」is incorrect.) あまり辛く**して**ほしくない would be okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, より少なく・少ない, literal translation of *less*, cannot be used to express comparative of inferiority. You need to use either antonyms or negation.

In the case of 辛い, there is no antonym that can be used regarding taste, so the options are (1) using negation as you did or (2) handling by using verbs meaning *reduce*.

For (2), most idiomatic are

- 辛さをもう少し控{ひか}えめにしてほしい
- 辛さをもう少し抑{おさ}えてほしい.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context, but if the person you are telling is the one preparing the food, you could say like 辛さを減らしてください (Please lessen the spiciness).